# How to embed a website in another website?

Tags: html, web, browser, embed

I have two websites, and I want to embed one in the other. I am aware that I can do this using either `iframe` or `embed`, but both only embed the webpage, not the entire website. I want it so that a user can click buttons, navigate, etc. throughout the site, accessing different URLs.

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` can indeed do that. Navigation inside the iframe does not affect the embedding webpage.